# SQL Server - Imbricate case return NULL

Tags: sql-server, case

I have to ensure the validity of my data base by using business rules.
I used a "select query" to browser every lines of my table.
When an error is identify, i insert this error in a error table with an message.

This is a simple example :

```
INSERT INTO SUPPLIER_ERR  (numSupplier, nameSupplier,telephoneNumber, MESSAGE)
SELECT numSupplier,nameSupplier,telephoneNumber,
CASE 
WHEN telephoneNumber  = ''
    then 'Must be filled'

When telephoneNumber NOT LIKE '+[0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9])%'
    then  'Must be to this format "+00(00)000000"'

END AS message

FROM dbo.supplier;
```

This solution works but sometime in my error table i have line with a null message when i imbricated case.
For example :

```
WHEN LEN(numCustomer,2) = 'CN' 
    then
    Case 
        when (RTRIM(mailCustomer) LIKE '.')
        THEN 'Must be x'        
    end
WHEN LEN(numCustomer) != 'CN' AND RTRIM(mailCustomer) != ''
    THEN  'Must be empty'
```

I understand why i got a null message (when it perform the first case and don't perform the second)

```
WHEN LEN(numCustomer,2) = 'CN' 
    then
    Case 
        when (RTRIM(mailCustomer) LIKE '.')
        THEN 'Must be x'        
    end
```

My question is :

**How can i check if my message is null ? (and not insert in my error table)**

Comment: You can have one more select-where from your current select-by-case, where clause to check **message is not null**.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i understood what you mean with @Bridge answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select statement is looking at every single row - not just those that you consider to have errors on. A `CASE` statement will return NULL for every row that does not meet one of the conditions you have checked against, if an `ELSE` clause is not supplied.

As such, you have two choices:

1. Check every row as you are now, and supply a default value for the error message where there weren't any errors found:

---

```
INSERT INTO SUPPLIER_ERR (numSupplier, nameSupplier,telephoneNumber, MESSAGE)
SELECT numSupplier,
       nameSupplier,
       telephoneNumber,
       CASE
         WHEN {Check 1 goes here} THEN 'Error message 1'
         WHEN {Check 2 goes here} THEN 'Error message 2'
         WHEN {Check 3 goes here} THEN 'Error message 3'
         ELSE 'No error detected'
       END
```

2. Only insert rows where an error was detected. Check with a `WHERE` clause - either check the rows match one of your conditions there, or cheat a little and just return those rows where the error message returned is not NULL:

---

```
INSERT INTO SUPPLIER_ERR (numSupplier, nameSupplier,telephoneNumber, MESSAGE)
SELECT numSupplier,
       nameSupplier,
       telephoneNumber,
       CASE
         WHEN {Check 1 goes here} THEN 'Error message 1'
         WHEN {Check 2 goes here} THEN 'Error message 2'
         WHEN {Check 3 goes here} THEN 'Error message 3'
       END
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN {Check 1 goes here} THEN 'Error message 1'
         WHEN {Check 2 goes here} THEN 'Error message 2'
         WHEN {Check 3 goes here} THEN 'Error message 3'
       END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The second choice looks like a good idea. i don't undestand how to implement the`WHERE`clause.  In the WHERE  CASE, i have to implement the same check as the first case ?

Comment: The where clause is just a copy of your CASE statement, with `IS NOT NULL` stuck on the end

Comment: For better SQL, I would suggest not repeat the long case statement in where clause. Use one more outer select from your current select and where message is not null on the outer select. This seems more elegant.

Comment: @daniel - I'd write the first statement as a CTE and alias it to something nice and short, for better readability. The theory is the same though! Performance shouldn't be affected either, it's smart enough to re-use the result of the calculation I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution works ! But i have to add a new column like a "code error" in my query where i write a code error (this code error is not contains in any table). Because of this column i had this message "Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'result'."  I hope you understand what i mean. You can check my example [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20f81/10](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20f81/10)

Comment: @Lyro You really should have asked your own question - but the answer is simple enough, you haven't given a column alias to `'Code error num_1'` - try `'Code error num_1' AS Description` or whatever you want to call it... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20f81/11